# Oracle: select by number name (seven -> 7)

Tags: oracle, select, text, numbers

Simple question: is there any way to select rows that contain a number by its number name? By that I mean I type 'seven' in the query, and get rows that contain '7'. I need this to do ordinals too: I type 'second', and get rows with a '2' in them.

I've been looking at Oracle Text but can't find anything that would do that.

Thanks!

--
llappall

Comment: I doubt there's a way built in.  How high would you need to support?  Such as `Four hundred eighty three thousand nine hundred twenty two`?

Answer (score 5):

```
select to_char(to_date(1,'J'),'Jsp') from dual;
```

HTH.

Alessandro

PS: @Mike: `select to_char(to_date(483922,'J'),'Jsp') from dual` works as well ;)

PPS: Forgot to mention: `select to_char(to_date(1,'J'),'Jspth') from dual;`

Comment: That's pretty handy, though I think you'd need the reserve of that function right?

Comment: "the reserve of that function"? Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Forgot to mention:

select to_char(to_date(1,'J'),'Jspth') from dual

Comment: Alessandro, great find!. It takes me ALMOST there. One last case that I can't make work:    7th -> seventh or seventh -> 7th. Any way to do that one?    I guess I could write a function for this one, since all numbers add th except for the few firt ones.

Comment: @archimede - Sorry, I meant the *reverse* of that function.  Going from name to number, so you could use it in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Not sure I understand sorry. Can't you do
...WHERE to_char(to_date(MY_NUMBER_FIELD,'J'),'Jspth') = 'Seventh'
?

Comment: The way I read it, the poster wanted to select rows that *contain* a number.  Like *seven* would match MY_NUMBER_FIELD=127.  To do that, you'd have to convert *seven* to *7* which that function wouldn't do.  But reading it again, it looks like your interpretation is correct..